# The ViewData item that has the key 'MyDrpId1' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using Asp.net MVC . I want to select value against drop downlist selected value. But i am getting exception . Here is my code
Controller

```
public ActionResult batsmenGrid()
    {

        List<batsmenModel> bM = new List<batsmenModel>();
     //   DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
        List<string> teams = new List<string>();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds = Connection.DAL.GetQuery("select * from batsmen"); // Using DAL file saved in App_Code folder
        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            bM.Add(new batsmenModel
            {
                _bid = Convert.ToInt32(dr["b_id"].ToString()),
                _bName = dr["b_name"].ToString(),
                _bAverage = dr["b_average"].ToString(),
                _team = dr["team"].ToString()
            });
        }
        var itms = bM.GroupBy(g => new { g._team }).Select(s => new { name = s.Key._team, count = s.Count(), details = s.Select(ss => ss) }).ToList();
        foreach (var v in itms)
        {
            teams.Add(v.name.ToString());
        }
        ViewBag.Teams = teams;   //View pe data phenknay k lia use kiya ha

        ViewBag.Team2 = new SelectList(teams.AsEnumerable());  // Another way to use dropdown list

        return View(bM);
    }

   [HttpPost]
    //[ActionName("GetbatsmenWithId")]  
     public ActionResult batsmenGrid(string MyDrpId1)
    {
        List<batsmenModel> bM = new List<batsmenModel>();
        //   DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
        List<String> teams = new List<String>();

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds = Connection.DAL.GetQuery("select * from batsmen where team = "+"'"+MyDrpId1+"'"); // Using DAL file saved in App_Code folder
        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            bM.Add(new batsmenModel
            {
                _bid = Convert.ToInt32(dr["b_id"].ToString()),
                _bName = dr["b_name"].ToString(),
                _bAverage = dr["b_average"].ToString(),
                _team = dr["team"].ToString()
            });
        }
        var itms = bM.GroupBy(g => new { g._team }).Select(s => new { name = s.Key._team, count = s.Count(), details = s.Select(ss => ss) }).ToList();
        //var itms = bM.GroupBy(g => new { g._team }).Select(s => new { name = s.Key._team, count = s.Count(), details = s.Select(ss => ss) }).ToList();
        foreach (var v in itms)
        {
            teams.Add(v.name.ToString());

        }


        ViewBag.Teams = teams;   


        return View(bM);
    }
```

Here is my view

```
 @model IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.Models.batsmenModel>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "batsmenGrid";
WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model, rowsPerPage: 2);
WebGrid grd = new WebGrid();

}
@using (Html.BeginForm("batsmenGrid", "batsmen"))
{


 @grid.GetHtml(

columns: new[]
{
grid.Column("_bid","Id"),                 //Models fields to display
grid.Column("_bName","Name"),
grid.Column("_bAverage","Average"),
grid.Column("_team","Team")



 }

 );
 @Html.DropDownList("MyDrpId1",(SelectList)ViewBag.Team2,"---Select Team---   ");


    <input type="submit" value="Get" />

}
```

When I open i browser I fetches data in gridview as well as drop down but when I select value and submit then it throws exception 
     The ViewData item that has the key 'MyDrpId1' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable'.

Comment: you have to add ``ViewBag.Team2 = new SelectList(teams.AsEnumerable());`` in the post action as well

Comment: As an aside, your code is vulnerable to Sql Injection attacks, especially given the parameter is a string. You'll want to replace `where team = "+"'"+MyDrpId1+"'"` with a parameterized equivalent.

Comment: Thankou so much @EhsanSajjad it works .